# sudo killall coreaudiod made it so I don't have any sound at all

Tags: macos, command-line, sound-volume

I ran into an issue where my volume buttons on my mac weren't able to adjust the volume of my computer. I sought a solution and someone suggested using `sudo killall coreaudiod`. Now I have no volume on my computer at all. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 70):

#### This command will do it:

```bsh
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.audio.coreaudiod && sudo launchctl start com.apple.audio.coreaudiod
```

#### Details

[Martin Strouhal's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246514/34759) doesn't work for OS X/macOS ≥ 10.12.4 due to removal of `com.apple.audio.coreaudiod` from **system integrity protection**'s `RemovableServices` whitelist in `/System/Library/Sandbox/com.apple.xpc.launchd.rootless.plist` [[1](https://gist.github.com/clburlison/54e2fd5c2ee42ced1c642c78c10a68e2)].

> ```
> sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod.plist
> /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod.plist: _
>    Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged
> ```

So instead of *unloading* the service, we instead just *restart* it.

Also, the latter command (`sudo launchctl start com.apple.audio.coreaudiod`) worked to restart the service after I had killed `coreaudiod` using `killall coreaudiod`.

Comment: On macOS 14.4, you just get `Not privileged to stop service.` (see my other comment above)

Comment: In macos 14.3, `sudo killall coreaudiod` works totally fine.

Answer (score 24):

You need to reload `coreaudiod` instead of killing it. This one-liner will fix broken sound without restarting your mac

`sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod.plist && sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod.plist`

Answer (score 6):

`sudo killall coreaudiod` should work to kill your audio drivers. It should reload itself within a fraction of a second.
(verified on my mbp running 10.14 but used this on a couple of previous versions)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the command:

```
sudo launchctl kill SIGTERM system/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an M1 pro. This is very frustrating so I just created an alias in my .zshrc.

`alias ar="sudo pkill coreaudiod -i"`

copy paste this line and it will just append+write to your .zshrc or .bashrc

`echo 'alias ar="sudo pkill coreaudiod -i"' >> ~/.zshrc; source ~/.zshrc`

Or if bash:

`echo 'alias ar="sudo pkill coreaudiod -i"' >> ~/.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc`

Sadly Still looking for a fix.

Hope this helps someone.

Happy Coding =)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the more modern form using this syntax:

```
sudo launchctl kickstart -kp system/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod
```

Comment: Seems Apple has deemed this "too dangerous" as of macOS 14.4, I am no longer allowed to kickstart my own daemons. Just get `Could not kickstart service "com.apple.audio.coreaudiod": 1: Operation not permitted`. I filed a ticket in case anyone else wants to hop on: FB13601345

Comment: In feedback assistant, how do I add your ticket (is it possible)

Comment: You can't directly add to my ticket, but if you mention the same bug ID in the notes I believe they get aggregated.

Comment: did what you said. Hopefully the feature is re-added

Comment: Holy crap, did some searching and quickly stumbled upon your Hacker News article, which is number 5 in the search results.